# Non-increasing function between two others?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:[1, \infty ) \rightarrow (0,1)$ is a continuous function which strictly decreases to $0$. Suppose $g: [1, \infty ) \rightarrow (0,1)$ is continuous, and $g<f$.  Does there exist a non-increasing continuous function $h$ with $g<h<f$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h'(x):=\sup_{y\geq x} g(y)$. This is clearly non-increasing and $g(x)\leq h'(x)$.

I claim that the supremum is "realized", that is, $h'(x)=g(y)$ for some $y\geq x$. Otherwise, we would get an infinite sequence $y_k$ such that $g(y_k)<g(y_{k+1})$ which would contradict the fact that $g<f$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f=0$.

Then we have 
$$h'(x)=g(y)<f(y)\leq f(x)$$
for some $y\geq x$, which implies $h'(x) < f(x)$.

So we have $g \leq h' < f$, $h'$ and $f$ are non-increasing, and you can define 
$$h:=\frac{1}{2} (h'+f).$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{g(x)} = 0$ since $0<g<f$ and $f$ decreases to $0$. Thus, for any $x\ge 1$, we have that $g$ attains a maximum on the set $[x,\infty)$. As such, let
$$s(x) = \sup\limits_{t\ge x}{g(t)}. $$
Then clearly $s(x)\ge g(x)$, and it is easy (albeit a bit tedious) to check that $s$ is continuous. Furthermore, for $x\ge 1$, if $t_x\ge x$ satisfies $s(x) = g(t_x)$, then
$$s(x) = g(t_x) < f(t_x) \le f(x). $$
Hence, $s<f$ on $[1,\infty)$. Finally, it is clear that $s$ is nonincreasing. Thus, if we take $h = \frac{f+s}{2}$, then $h$ is continuous, with $g\le s < h < f$, and since $h$ is an average of a strictly decreasing function and an nonincreasing function, we have that $h$ is in fact strictly decreasing.

Comment: I just posted an identical answer, in the same second :)

Comment: @PeterFranek I actually saw your answer right before I was about to post. I considered not posting since the answers are more or less the same, but I decided to go ahead anyway since I already worked on it.

Comment: Thanks very much, guys.  I'll just go with priority since they're so similar.